# Not able to connect to parse server on android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

May be I something missing Android studio shows me error
Error: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure

Below is my menifist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.m1.parsedemo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I added below code under `<application` which shows me error

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/parse_app_id" /> // error line
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="@string/parse_client_key" /> // error line
```

now the error is error: failed processing manifest. I remove `@string/` from the error line now the project build successfully but the previous error occurred. I am using Parse-SDK-Android : 1.18.5 and below is mainActivity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().logOut();
        ParseObject score = new ParseObject("Score");
        score.put("username", "manish");
        score.put("score", 862);
        score.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {

                    Log.i("SaveInBackground", "Successful");

                } else {


                    Log.i("SaveInBackground", "Failed. Error: " + e.toString());

                }

            }
        });


        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
    }

}
```

and App.java file is

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .applicationId("abc")
                .clientKey("xyz")
                .server("http://some_address:80/parse/")
                .build()
        );


        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

    }
}
```

I stuck here What I am doing wrong here ? I am following rob tutorial of android series and downloaded their app which runs fine and connect to my parse server but it has old parse sdk on it.
Thnx

Comment: probably the URL is incorrect. Are you sure you have a parse server running on http://35.153.239.137:80/parse/ ?

Comment: Url is correct I just used the dummy url.

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can follow the steps in this link just change the application id , client id an url to your required 
https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/parse-sdk

download the project from  thi
guess you are studying from rob percival ,This worked for me , try this link

Answer (score 1):

**Connect to Parse Server on AWS** 
In Android Studio, you should use the latest version of Android Studio when set up Parse Server. If you use SSH client to connect to instance. Using Public IPv4 address in instance information to enter IP address. After that, browse key at SSH/AUTH and enter username: bitnami in the terminal. To get your app information, enter cd stack/parse then cat config.json. Using "http://ec2-4-150-20-8.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:80/parse/" for example, to enter server url in your app. Remember :80/parse at the end of the link. To check your server on web browser, using "http://ec2-4-150-20-8.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/apps" for example, remember /apps at the end. Using the default username: user and password is your masterKey to enter. 
In X-code, using the server url you get when connecting to instance in your app instead.